# Why didn't Brad Pitt win Best Picture Oscar Award for Departed, even though he served as producer for the film?

Tags: academy-awards

Why was Bard Pitt not nominated for the Oscar for Departed (2006)?

Bradley Cooper's name is listed for Best Picture for Oscars because he served as producer for [American Sniper](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2179136/):
[image]
Then why was Brad Pitt's name not listed for [Departed (2006)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0407887/), even though he also served as producer for the movie?:
[image]

Comment: I'm not actually following your line of reasoning. Perhaps it is a misunderstanding of language. Could you please re-write your question so as to be more clear?

Comment: @CGCampbell i edited the question.

Comment: This is actually a fairly decent question. My guess (and thus not an answer) is that even though Plan B (Pitt's company) bought the rights to Internal Affairs, it turned over the actual production to GK (Graham King's company). While Copper's 22 & Indiana Pictures was intimately involved (with Cooper staring at WB's insistence). 22&I never 'turned over' production to anyone else, they simply shared it.

Comment: @CGCampbell If you were referring to the original movie (not law enforcement) in your comment, then I think the name is Infernal Affairs.

Comment: The best picture award is given to the Movie not the producer. The recipient of the award are the three major producers of the movie. So I don't know how Brad Pitt can be 'nominated' for the award.

Comment: Yep, chaitanya89 is right, it's Infernal Affairs directed by Andrew Lau. But we're missing the point aren't we CGCampbell? ;)

Comment: Yes, I typed Internal by accident and didn't catch it; I 'm not sure what "point" I'm missing. I had no idea why Pitt did not receive it and was guess (as I said.)

Answer (score 12):

According to [Access Hollywood](http://www.accesshollywood.com/brad-pitt-denied-departed-oscar-bid_article_3775):

> The Academy of Motion Picture Arts and Sciences has ruled that only
>   Graham King will get the credit for the crime drama “The Departed,”
>   leaving Brad Pitt and Paramount Pictures studio chief Brad Grey out in
>   the cold.
>
> [...]
>
> When a film wins an Oscar, it’s the producer who accepts the golden
>   statuette and gives the acceptance speech. Rules adopted by the
>   academy in 2000 limits credited producers to three in order to avoid
>   handing awards to a mob of “producers,” some of whom may have gained
>   the credit for little or no effort.
>
> [...]
>
> The academy also decided that only one producer would get credit for
>   the Martin Scorsese film “The Departed.”

Comment: But *American Sniper* has more than three credited producers and was made post-2000.

Comment: @OrangeDog And the Academy rules on which ones are allowed to come on stage. As explained in the answer. Just like happened with The Departed.

Comment: That wasn't clear.